# D3 - Updating Choropleth csv to change mapping of colours

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, geojson

Hi I'm new to D3 and am having trouble updating my map through buttons that trigger a function to load a new csv. I looked at similar posts which mentioned that I would only need to update the section which fills the map with colours, and have tried to adapt this but clicking on my button doesn't affect the map.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Setting path fills dynamically to generate a choropleth</title>
        <h1>Relation between Managers and Tertiary Education </h1>
        <div id="option1">
            <input type="button"value="Education"onclick="viewEducation()" />
        </div>
        <div id="option2">
            <input type="button"value="Managers"onclick="viewManagers()" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 1000;
            var h = 600;

            var path = d3.geoPath()
                         .projection(d3.geoMercator()
                         .center([151,-33.5])
                         .scale(17000)
                         .translate([w/2,h/2]));

            //Define quantize scale to sort data values into buckets of color
            var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
                                .range(["rgb(237,248,233)","rgb(200,235,198)", "rgb(186,228,179)","rgb(146,208,140)", "rgb(116,196,118)", "rgb(88,178,100)", "rgb(49,163,84)", "rgb(20,130,60)", "rgb(0,109,44)"])
                                .domain([6274, 39796]);
                                //Colors derived from ColorBrewer, by Cynthia Brewer, and included in
                                //https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in agriculture data
            d3.csv("ManagerPercentage.csv", function(d) { d.value = parseFloat(d.value); parseFloat(d.value1); return d; }, function(data) {

                //Set input domain for color scale

                color.domain([
                    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
                    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })
                ]);

                //Load in GeoJSON data
                d3.json("australia_adm2.json", function(json) {

                    //Merge the ag. data and GeoJSON
                    //Loop through once for each ag. data value
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        //Grab state name
                        var dataState = data[i].state;

                        //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                        var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].value);

                        //Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
                        for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                            var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.sa4_name11;

                            if (dataState == jsonState) {

                                //Copy the data value into the JSON
                                json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;

                                //Stop looking through the JSON
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                    svg.selectAll("path")
                       .data(json.features)
                       .enter()
                       .append("path")
                       .attr("d", path)
                       .style("fill", function(d) {
                            //Get data value
                            var value = d.properties.value;

                            if (value) {
                                //If value exists…
                                return color(value);
                            } else {
                                //If value is undefined…
                                return "#ccc";
                            }
                       });

                });

            });

function viewEducation () {
                    d3.select("option1")
                       d3.csv("EducationPercentage.csv", function(data) {
                                         svg.selectAll("path")
                                         .style("fill", function(d) {
                                         var value = d.properties.value;

                                         if (value) {
                                         return color(value);
                                        } else {
                                         return "#ccc";
                                     }
                                });

                 });
}

function viewManagers () {
                    d3.select("option2")
                       d3.csv("ManagerPercentage.csv", function(data) {
                                         svg.selectAll("path")
                                         .style("fill", function(d) {
                                         var value = d.properties.value;

                                         if (value) {
                                         return color(value);
                                        } else {
                                         return "#ccc";
                                     }
                                });

                 });
             });
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```